# Bank IT Job if the Salary is not Given by the Bank

Tags: halal-haram, work, banking, government

As-Salamu Alaykum.

I am in a dilemma right now.

I know that to be considered a halal income source, two conditions must be satisfied:

1. The work itself is not haram.
2. The salary must be from halal source.

I have done some research and it's seems that there are different views regarding bank jobs that do not involve dealing with interest directly, like guard job, programmer etc. But even those scholars who support these types of jobs say that it's better to avoid.

The question I have is that if I work in a bank as a programmer or as a maintenance engineer and ***I am paid directly by the government and not by the bank***, then would my job be considered completely halal? Will my earnings be considered **completely halal** and not **predominantly halal?**

And also is it halal to work in Capital Market related jobs (investment banking, stock market, asset management)?

Answer (score 1):

In one sense, it is not Halal. But another sense it is not

If your country is not a Islamic country, you cannot avoid the country's economic system that stands on a Haram basis. So in that country every money exchanging facts is haram directly or indirectly.

So I think you are standing on a boundary. If you find a better option you can choose that.

May Allah help you.